# setCustomValidity() gets stuck on last validation checks, it doesn't submit form after it mets all validation checks

Tags: javascript

here is my working code on password field validation check. it works fine while all criterion are met but when it doesn't it gets stuck on last validation checks in case of submitting form after validation completions!!

Please have a look [here][1]

```
[1]: https://codepen.io/bappyasif/pen/vYNoEap?editors=1112

var firstPasswordInput = document.querySelector("#first");
var secondPasswordInput = document.querySelector("#second");
var submit = document.querySelector("#submit");

let symbolPattern = /[\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*]/g;
let numberPattern = /\d/g;
let lowercasePattern = /[a-z]/g;
let uppercasePattern = /[A-Z]/g;
let unallowedCharacters = /[^A-z0-9\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*]/g;

submit.onclick = function () {
  let firstPassword = firstPasswordInput.value;
  let secondPassword = secondPasswordInput.value;

  if (firstPassword === secondPassword && firstPassword.length > 0) {
    checkRequirements();
  } else {
    secondPasswordInput.setCustomValidity("Passwords must match!");
  }

  function checkRequirements() {
    if (firstPassword.length < 6) {
      firstPasswordInput.setCustomValidity("Fewer than 6 characters");
      //   return;
    } else if (firstPassword.length >= 10) {
      firstPasswordInput.setCustomValidity("greater than 10 characters");
      //   return;
    }

    // Pattern Checks
    if (!firstPassword.match(symbolPattern)) {
      firstPasswordInput.setCustomValidity(
        "missing a symbol (!, @, #, $, %, ^, &, *"
      );

      if (!firstPassword.match(numberPattern)) {
        firstPasswordInput.setCustomValidity("missing a number");
        //   return false;
        //   return;
      }

      if (!firstPassword.match(lowercasePattern)) {
        firstPasswordInput.setCustomValidity("missing a lowercase letter");
        //   return;
      }

      if (!firstPassword.match(uppercasePattern)) {
        firstPasswordInput.setCustomValidity("missing an uppercase letter");
        //   return;
      }

      if (firstPassword.match(unallowedCharacters)) {
        firstPasswordInput.setCustomValidity("includes illegal character: ");
        //   return;
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Form Related HTML Tags For Shared Code Snippet:

```
  <label>
    <input id="first" type="password" placeholder="New password" autofocus maxlength="100" required />
  </label>
  <!-- type="password" -->
  <label>
    <input id="second" type="password" placeholder="Repeat password" autofocus maxlength="100" required />
  </label>
  <input id="submit" type="submit" />
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please review this [Prevent Posts w/No Code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code) and post the code here.

Comment: @JasonArmstrong that link has code in it, or is there anything that i am not doing it right for others to see?!

Comment: The problem with only posting a link to the code and not the code itself is that when the codepen link goes stale, anyone who comes here in the future will not be able to understand the problem and any potential answers that are offered up. Therefore, it's best to include the code directly here, so future readers facing similar problems to you can benefit as well.

Comment: @JasonArmstrong thank you so much for your reply, I would do that from now on :) ;)